# How can I get user responses in surveygizmo?

Tags: rest, getresponse

I want to get user's response along with question from surveyGizmo. I am getting list of questions and possible answers.

But I want specific answer which user has given during survey.

> `https://restapi.surveygizmo.com/v5/survey/123456/surveyresponse?api_token='some token'`

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest solution, but only on python and missing some profit for you, becasue your task is not exact. It's a general way to print all answers. And you can choose that you need.

```
#needed packages
from surveygizmo import SurveyGizmo 
import json

#auth
sg = SurveyGizmo(
             api_version='v4', 
             response_type='json', 
             api_token = api_token, 
             api_token_secret = api_token_secret
            )
 #get data from your account as json (as I know json is optional) 
 answers = json.loads(sg.api.surveyresponse.list(surveyid, resultperpage=resultperpage, page=page) 

 #in answers['data'] are saved onlu responses
 list_of_answers = answers['data']

 #using loop you can get all answers on all questions 
 for answer_index in list_of_respondents:
      for question_index, question_value in enumerate(list_of_answers[answer_index])

           #SurveyGizmo data structure contains answers with labels like '[question(question_id), [option(option_id)' — that's why we need this 'if' 
           if question_value.startswith('[question'):
                print(list_of_answers[answer_index][question_value])
```

Actually I'm working with it now and try to transfer all sg-data to sql like database and it makes me to do find simpliest ways to work. So f you give more information, I can make more profit for you.